# Get all Youtube video's from posts and embed them on a different page

Tags: posts, embed, youtube, oembed

Is this possible? I want to let it check all my posts to see if there is a embedded Youtube video. If so, I want to show that on a different page, embedded and linking to that particular post...

I tried the following snippet, but that did not work for me. It doesn't embed a video...

```
function aihato_latest_video() {
  $query_args = array(
    's' => 'youtube.com/watch?v=',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
  );

  $posts = get_posts( $query_args );
  $post1 = $posts[0];

  $matches = array();

  preg_match('|http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|', $post1->post_content, $matches);
  $v = $matches[1];
?>
<object width="415" height="250">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $v ?>&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $v ?>&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="415" height="250"></embed>
</object>
<?php
}
```

Edit: This is working neither:

```
function aihato_latest_video() {
  $query_args = array(
    's' => 'youtube.com/watch?v=',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
  );

$posts = get_posts( $query_args );
foreach ($posts as $p) {
  $matches = array();
  preg_match('|http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|', $p->post_content, $matches);
?>

 <?php if (!empty($matches[1])) { ?>
    <object width="415" height="250">
      <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $matches[1] ?>&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>
      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
      <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
      <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $matches[1] ?>&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="415" height="250"></embed>
    </object><?php
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Where does that code fail?

Comment: Everywhere where I put it in... It does not embed the video, although it shows me something like a video (a white background). But it's not getting all video's at all...

Comment: You missed the point. I am trying to prompt you to do some of your own debugging. Does the query fail? Does the `preg_match` fail? Where does this go wrong?

Comment: If I'd know that, I wouldn't ask that and would have solved it myself. Don't know what is going wrong, but there is going something wrong, that's for sure.

Comment: Use `var_dump` to dump your variables and see what is actually happening-- basic low-tech PHP debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Another method can be like this, On the current post when you save look for youtube video in the content, if found save it to the transient `'videos'` and the post_id *(for the link to the post later)* insted of regex im using [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_youtube_videos' );
function save_youtube_videos( $post_id ) 
{
    $saved   = get_transient( 'videos' ); // If we have videos before
    $videos  = !empty( $saved ) ? $saved : array();
    $content = isset( $_POST['post_content'] ) ? $_POST['post_content'] : null;

    if( $content )
    {
        parse_str( parse_url( $content, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $video );
        if( !in_array( $video['v'], $videos ) )
        {
            $videos[ $post_id ] = $video['v']; // Push post_id and the vide_id
            set_transient( 'videos', $videos );  // Save all videos as array
        }
    }
}
```

Save your post_id and youtube_id if your post have one. So on update or publish look for a video using parse_str and parse_url, if we find one add it to the transient cache so we dont need to find all the posts again.

```
function get_youtube_archive( $width = '415', $height = '250' )
{
    $videos = get_transient( 'videos' );

    if( !empty( $videos ) && count( $videos ) > 0 )
    {
        $output = '';

        foreach( $videos as $key => $value ) 
        {
            $output .= '<object width="'. $width .'" height="'. $height .'">';
                $output .= '<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'. $value .'/&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>';
                $output .= '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>';
                $output .= '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>';
                $output .= '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'. $value .'&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="'. $width .'" height="'. $height .'"></embed>';
            $output .= '</object>';

            $output .= '<a href="'. get_permalink( $key ) .'" alt="Go to post">Go to post</a>';
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

And a listing function so you can get the videos by just add:

```
echo get_youtube_archive();
```

Where you want them. You have to save the posts where you have videos for this to work.

Comment: Thanks Pontus, but I get this error: `array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given`

Comment: I do like your general idea. But hooking a function to the `save_post` action that retrieves and iterates over *all posts*? *Every time* a post is created, updated, autosaved? That is humongous overhead!

Comment: @Pontus Abrahamsson: Your edit does not give me errors, but it does not show anything either...

Comment: @JohannesPille yeah ofcourse! im just tired.. hehe, now it saves the current edited/published posts and looks for videos. johan, edit a post that have a video and save it again, and add the get_youtube_archive() function where you want the videos.

Comment: I like the idea too but you'd need a two-part system to make it efficient. One part to run once and initialize your transient (or other value) for all existing posts, and another part to check only the current post for videos as it is saved.

Comment: @s_ha_dum yeah, but i think its better to have all video id:s saved with the post id than run a get_posts query every time and search for youtube.com/watch?v=. Now it also just save the current post.

Comment: @PontusAbrahamsson : That is basically what I said, but you do need to query all the posts to catch any videos in previously saved posts. After that you only need to check the current one.

Comment: @s_ha_dum my bad, im off to bed now! If you don't have previous posts this works or else you have to go and save them again.

Comment: Nope nope and nope. I tried saving my post with a video in it once again and added your codes of course, but nothing is happening. No video...

Comment: Try to add the both function to your themes functions.php and right after (just for test) echo get_youtube_archive(); and go to posts->edit post and add: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmaBXE17S00 and save. this works for me

Comment: @Johan have you manage it to work?

Comment: Well Pontus, almost there. I see something being embed, but not the video. It shows me a white square and does nothing. FYI: I have added the two codes in `functions.php` and put the echo in a different page...

Answer (score 3):

Without even running that code I can see a pretty significant problem. You describe the goal as to "check all my posts to see if there is a embedded YouTube video" but the query is restricted to only one post.

And then, you are only attempting to use the very first post in the results (if the query works at all) anyway so there is no way that this is going to get all the YouTube videos from all the posts. If it is lucky it will get the videos from one post only. The first thing you need to do is Loop through all the posts. Untested, but something like this:

```
$posts = get_posts( $query_args );
foreach ($posts as $p) {
  $matches = array();
  preg_match('|http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|', $p->post_content, $matches);
  if (!empty($matches[1])) { ?>
    <object width="415" height="250">
      <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $matches[1] ?>&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>
      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
      <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
      <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $matches[1] ?>&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="415" height="250"></embed>
    </object><?php
  }
}
```

Your `regex` is also wrong. YouTube video IDs have underscores.

Put altogether:

```
function aihato_latest_video() {
  $query_args = array(
    's' => 'youtube.com/watch?v=',
  );

  $posts = get_posts( $query_args );
  foreach ($posts as $p) {
    $matches = array();
    preg_match('|http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|', $p->post_content, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[1])) { ?>
      <object width="415" height="250">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $matches[1] ?>&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $matches[1] ?>&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="415" height="250"></embed>
      </object><?php
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I use this: `function aihato_latest_video() {
  $query_args = array(
    's' => 'youtube.com/watch?v=',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
  );

 AND HERE GOES YOUR CODE` it says `unexpected end`

Comment: You didn't close the function with a `}`.

Comment: Check my edit, I tried that, but still the same...

Comment: You still didn't close the function correctly. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks, I put your code in `functions.php` and used `<?php aihato_latest_video(); ?>` in tag.php to try it, but nothing happened at all...

Comment: See the edit. I found a couple of more problems.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing once again. No video is showing....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9862/discussion-between-johan-and-s-ha-dum)